# Why can't VHDL find the work.entity all though the compile order is correct?

Tags: vhdl

Consider this code:

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.std_definitions.all;

entity Blink_Entity is

generic (BITWIDTH : integer;
    count_to : integer 
        );

port (
       start_button_i : in std_ulogic;
       reset_i : in std_ulogic;
       clk_i : in std_ulogic;
       led_o : in std_ulogic
       );

end Blink_Entity;

architecture bhv of Blink_Entity is

signal counter_restart_strobe : std_ulogic := '0';
signal counter_value : std_ulogic_vector(BITWIDTH-1 downto 0);

begin

Counter : entity work.Counter_Entity

generic map (
 BITWIDTH => BITWIDTH
)

port map (
        clk_i => clk_i,
    reset_i => reset_i,
    counter_restart_strobe_i => counter_restart_strobe,
    counter_value_o => counter_value
       );

FSM : entity work.FSM_Entity

generic map (
 BITWIDTH => BITWIDTH,
 count_to => count_to
 )

port map (

        start_button_i => start_button_i,
    clock_i => clock_i,
    reset_i => reset_i,
    counter_value_i => counter_value,
    counter_restart_strobe_o => counter_restart_strobe,
    led_o => led_o
    );
    
end architecture;
```

And these two entities;

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity counter is 

generic (BITWIDTH : integer);

port( clk_i : in std_ulogic;
      reset_i : in std_ulogic;
      counter_restart_strobe_i : in std_ulogic;
      counter_value_o : out std_ulogic_vector(BITWIDTH downto 0)
    );
end counter;

    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity FSM is 

generic( BITWIDTH : integer;
         count_to : integer
        );
port( start_button_i: in std_ulogic;
      clock_i: in std_ulogic;
      reset_i: in std_ulogic;
      counter_value_i: in std_ulogic_vector(BITWIDTH-1 downto 0);
      restart_counter_strobe_o : out std_ulogic;
      led_o : out std_ulogic
   );

end entity;
```

Now I've setup the compile order that the last one to compile is the Blinking entity,after counter and FSM.This is the error I get;

```
** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.counter_entity.
** Error (suppressible): C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\UE_2\Blinking_Entity.vhd(28): (vcom-1195) Cannot find expanded name "work.Counter_Entity".
** Error: C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\UE_2\Blinking_Entity.vhd(28): Unknown expanded name.
** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find work.fsm_entity.
** Error (suppressible): C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\UE_2\Blinking_Entity.vhd(41): (vcom-1195) Cannot find expanded name "work.FSM_Entity".
** Error: C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\UE_2\Blinking_Entity.vhd(41): Unknown expanded name.
** Note: C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\UE_2\Blinking_Entity.vhd(58): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

I am not seeing the reason this is occurring. Any thoughts?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.7 Component instantiation statements
11.7.1 General, para 3 (in part) "The entity name, if present, shall be the name of a previously analyzed entity declaration; if an architecture identifier appears in the instantiated unit, then that identifier shall be the same as the simple name of an architecture body associated with the entity declaration denoted by the corresponding entity name."

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I found the error, a silly one at that.

```vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.std_definitions.all;

entity Blink_Entity is

generic (BITWIDTH : integer;
    count_to : integer 
        );

port (
       start_button_i : in std_ulogic;
       reset_i : in std_ulogic;
       clk_i : in std_ulogic;
       led_o : in std_ulogic
       );

end Blink_Entity;

architecture bhv of Blink_Entity is

signal counter_restart_strobe : std_ulogic := '0';
signal counter_value : std_ulogic_vector(BITWIDTH-1 downto 0);

begin

Counter : entity work.counter

generic map (
 BITWIDTH => BITWIDTH
)

port map (
        clk_i => clk_i,
    reset_i => reset_i,
    counter_restart_strobe_i => counter_restart_strobe,
    counter_value_o => counter_value
       );

FSM : entity work.FSM

generic map (
 BITWIDTH => BITWIDTH,
 count_to => count_to
 )

port map (

        start_button_i => start_button_i,
    clock_i => clock_i,
    reset_i => reset_i,
    counter_value_i => counter_value,
    counter_restart_strobe_o => counter_restart_strobe,
    led_o => led_o
    );
    
end architecture;
```

I used the file names, and not the names of the entities (counter and FSM).